# Python project help (classes/expected type)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project for school, simulating a payroll program, and I am getting an error. The error I am getting is 
'Expected type 'Classification', got 'Employee' instead'. The relevant code is (I put *** around the code generating the error, it is the 5th function under the Employee Class).

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, emp_id, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zipcode, clas = None):
        self.emp_id = emp_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.classification = clas

    def make_hourly(self, hourly_rate):
        self.clas = Hourly(hourly_rate)
        self.classification = self.clas

    def make_salaried(self, salary):
        self.clas = Salaried(salary)
        self.classification = self.clas

    def make_commissioned(self, salary, rate):
        self.clas = Commissioned(rate, salary)
        self.classification = self.clas

    def issue_payment(self):
        ***pay = Classification.compute_pay(self)***
        print('Mailing', pay, 'to', self.first_name, self.last_name, 'at', self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)


class Classification(ABC):
    ''' Interface for employee classifications '''
    @abstractmethod
    def compute_pay(self):
        pass

class Hourly(Classification):
    ''' Manages timecard info. Computes pay '''
    def __init__(self, hourly_rate):
        self.hourly_rate = hourly_rate
        self.timecards = []     # A list of floats representing hours worked

    def compute_pay(self):
        for i in list_of_timecards:
            if i[0] == self.emp_id:
                self.timecards.extend(i[1:])
        total = list(map(float, self.timecards))
        total = sum(total)
        self.timecards.clear()
        return total * self.hourly_rate

    def add_timecard(self, hours):
        self.timecards.append(hours)

class Salaried(Classification):
    def __init__(self, salary):
        self.salary = salary

    def compute_pay(self):
        return self.salary / 24

class Commissioned(Salaried):
    def __init__(self, salary, commission_rate):
        self.commission_rate = commission_rate
        self.salary = salary
        self.receipts = []

    def add_receipt(self, amount):
        self.receipts.append(amount)

    def compute_pay(self):
        for i in list_of_receipts:
            if i[0] == self.emp_id:
                self.receipts.extend(i[1:])
            total = list(map(float, self.receipts))
            total = sum(total)
            self.receipts.clear()
        return (self.salary / 24) + ((self.commission_rate / 100) * total)
```

My understanding of the problem is that I need to pass my 'employee' object to the 'compute_pay' function, which then passes it to the relevant child class (hourly etc...) to run and return the result. I have tried changing 
pay = Classification.compute_pay(self)
to
pay = Classification.compute_pay(self.clas)
however that returns error 'AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'clas'
which makes no sense. Maybe it is that I am not assigning the employees to the class correctly?
The code for that is (it pulls from a CSV file, and it is pulling the data correctly and generating the class objects, I have checked)

```
def load_employees():
    f = open("employees.csv")
    f.readline() # skip header line
    for line in f:
        fields = line.strip().split(',')
        emp = Employee(*fields[:7])
        if fields[7] == '3':
            clas = Hourly(fields[10])  # Need to define Hourly
            emp.classification = clas
        elif fields[7] == '2':
            clas = Commissioned(fields[8], fields[9])
            emp.classification = clas
        elif fields[7] == '1':
            clas = Salaried(fields[8])
            emp.classification = clas
        employees.append(emp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will figure out your line `Classification.compute_pay(self)`:

- Classification => the class Classification
- compute_pay => class
- method  self => this = an Employee instance

`pass` means do nothing and is used to avoid unneccessary code.
Every class method has `self` as an argument to allow refering to this instance of the class. 
To pass an argument (here your employee) use a parameter. Also implementing a method of the parent class overrides this method.
Every function `compute_pay` should have a second argument

```
def compute_pay(self, employee):
    # do your stuff
```

And then you can use this line in `issue_payment`

```
pay = self.clas.compute_pay(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I am still quite new to python so just a quick followup question.
when you make it 
pay = Hourly.compute_pay(self), I think the point of it going directly to classification is because it could be hourly.compute_pay or Salaried_compute_pay etc...
Second, 
def compute_pay(self, employee):
    for i in list_of_receipts:
        if i[0] == employee.emp_id:
           do the other stuff
The thing there is that, again, it could be hourly or salaried or commissioned. Is there a way to check 'clas' an employee has, given that 'clas' is an object its self?

Comment: sorry, formatting. I havent figured out how to format on this platform, it seems to delete my extra white space.

Comment: I've changed my code. It now automatically calls the right method. And yes html ignores multiple whitespace.

Comment: As for 'should self.clas be the same as self.classification', I do believe so. self.classification = clas. Our professor gives us some code and we then fill out the rest, and basically the first have of class Employee was given to us, including that line. Also, yes I do see your new code, but what is you suggested for def compute_pay still would only work for hourly employees.

Comment: I just tried pay = self.class.compute_pay(self) and it says employee has no attribute 'clas'. that just makes no sense tho.

Comment: Have you called one of the make methods before?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean by make method. Are you referring to where my code assigns employees to their 'clas' or is this something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here,

Firstly, your `Employee` instance has two attributes: `clas` and `classification`. However, in your constructor, only `classification` is set.

```
def __init__(...
...
self.classification = clas
```

But `self.clas` is not set to anything. That's why you are getting that error `'Employee' object has no attribute 'clas'`. It is only set when one of the `make_hourly`, `make_salaried`, or `make_commissioned` methods are invoked. So when you load the employees CSV, instead of manually creating the instance like you are doing here

```
clas = Hourly(fields[10])
```

you should be calling the method `make_hourly` on your `emp` instance, like so

```
emp.make_hourly(fields[10])
```

It's worth noting that `fields[10]` is terrible naming. Instead of unpacking all the fields at once, try to unpack them during the for loop:

```
for a, b, c, d in csv: 
    ...
```

Secondly, this line of code is wrong in multiple ways

```
pay = Classification.compute_pay(self)
```

`compute_pay` is not a static function or a `classmethod`. So it shouldn't be called on the `Classification` class itself, but the `Classification` instance. This is what you stored in your `self.clas` attribute. So, `compute_pay` should be called on `self.clas`:

```
def issue_payment(self):
    pay = self.clas.compute_pay()
    ...
```

In addition to that, when you call a method of a class from inside of another method in the same class, you don't ever need to pass the `self` argument. It is implied. So even if `compute_pay` was static or a class method, which it isn't, it would be called like so,

```
Classification.compute_pay()
```

Notice there is no `self` inside the parentheses. Similarly, when you call another method that is not static, `self` is never passed as an argument:

```
def my_method(self):
    self.another_method()
```